# activate an animation only once inside an if statement

Tags: android, android-animation, countdowntimer

I have a countdown timer and I used some if statements to mark certain intervals within the countdown. I want to play an animation where I move an TextView from one point to another but I want it to be done once within the interval. I have for example set an interval from 0 to 60000 milliseconds I want the animation to play once during that interval, with the following animation:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-50%"
        android:duration="800" />
</set>
```

Part of my timer code:

```
     private void startTimer() {
        Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "CHECK","Entered startTimer() method");
        millisInFuture = mTimeLeftInMillis;
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
                final long millisPassed = millisInFuture - mTimeLeftInMillis;
                progress = (int) (millisPassed * 100 / millisInFuture);
                pb.setProgress(progress);
                pb2.setProgress(0);
                pb3.setProgress(0);


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //Key: 60 sec
                if (millisInFuture == 480000) {
                    if (millisPassed <= 60000 || (millisPassed > 180000 && millisPassed <= 240000) || (millisPassed > 300000 && millisPassed <= 360000 || (millisPassed > 420000 && millisPassed <= 480000))) {
//                        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(tool1mode1.this, R.anim.fade_in);
//                        stepupimage.setAnimation(animation);
                        setflowrate();
                        Log.println(Log.ASSERT,"CHECK","Check that the first if statement of key 60 is entered");
                        statusIfUp();
                        time_of_stage = (millisInFuture - millisPassed) % 60000;
                        progress2 = (int) (time_of_stage*100 / 60000);
                        Log.println(Log.VERBOSE,"CHECK","TIME OF STAGE = "+time_of_stage);
                        Log.println(Log.VERBOSE,"CHECK","progress2= "+progress2);
                        pb2.setProgress(progress2);
                        updateStageUpCount();

                        upArrowAnimation();
```

*setflowrate* is the method I use to call my animation

```
 private void setflowrate()
{
    flow.setText(String.valueOf(num) + " GPM");
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(tool1mode1.this, R.anim.move_up);
    flow.setAnimation(animation);
    linearlayoutofflow.setAnimation(animation);
    progressBar.setAnimation(animation);

}
```

flow, linearlayoutoutflow, progressbar  are supposed to move upwards during the time intervals above but I want the movement to occur only once per interval.

Edit: the problem is that the animation keeps looping. I want it to occur once inside the onTick method which gets called every second. The time intervals I have designated using the if statements I want the animation to occur in them only once.

Comment: What is your code doing right now? Is the animation playing several times, or is it even playing? Please be more specific of what exactly is not working.

Comment: the animation is supposed to move the object being animated upwards or downwards. What happens is that it keeps repeating that because the animation is called inside the onTick method which is called very second. I want it to play just once rather than constantly looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way that comes to my mind would be setting a Boolean flag, if true play the animation and set the boolean to false, if false do not play the animation.

```
private boolean animate = true;

private void setflowrate() {
    if(animate) {
        flow.setText(String.valueOf(num) + " GPM");
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(tool1mode1.this, R.anim.move_up);
        flow.setAnimation(animation);
        linearlayoutofflow.setAnimation(animation);
        progressBar.setAnimation(animation);
        animate = false;
    }
}
```

At the end of all processes, or as you say 'the interval' you set the flag to true again in case you want to be able to restart the animation.

Comment: appreciated I''ll try it out

Comment: Appreciated, It worked like a charm. This website needs more people like you.

Comment: No problem. I would appreciate If you would also upvote my answer

Comment: and believe me this website has the best people in the world(me excluded:)